# How to cancel a particular pendingIntent with specific request_code?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to make an app which can ADD, VIEW & CANCEL an alarm. I have designed a database for that. Viewing and creating new alarm works perfectly.

But the problem is to CANCEL the alarm. All alarms are set by the same `pendingIntent` with a different `request_code`. The `request_code` is taken from database entries (i.e. the ID field). If I use the `cancel(pendingIntent)` method, it will cancel all alarms. But I just want to cancel the specific alarm with a specific `request_code`. Here is my creating alarm code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, d1_on.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, user_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Now when I click the CANCEL button it will ask for `user_id`. Then it will delete that row from database. It's ok... but now I want to stop that specific alarm with `request_code` set to user_id.

Or please explain to me how to cancel a `pendingIntent` created in `alarmActivity` class through `alarmReceiver` class.

Answer (score 3):

Recreate the `pendingIntent` just as you originally created it

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, user_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

then you can cancel it with

```
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542099/cant-stop-the-ringing-alarm-from-another-activity#51542099 @codeMagic