# Can't stop the ringing alarm from another activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am new to android ,Here I am practicing my first app (Alarm App).

I have an issue in my app that I can't stop the alarm once a alarm is triggered it's keep on ringing can't get stopped.

In my app I have 2 activities and a AlarmReceiver .

From the AlarmActivity.java I have set the alarm ,when the specific time is reached the Alarmreceiver.java will get triggered and the alarm started to ring and showing a wakeup screen .

From the WakeUpScreen.java I have a stop button by using that I need to stop the current ringing alarm .

I don't have any issues in logcat too.

AlarmActivity.java

```
  public void stopAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("ALARM_OFF");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, mAlarmId, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
```

I have this AlarmStop() function in my AlarmActivity.java which will get hit when I press the stop button in wakeupscreen.java

**When I am try to debug the stop process the debugger moved all the lines in the stopAlarm() function but the Intent is not worked that's why the AlarmReceiver.java file is not get called ,I mean,The debugger moved all the lines in the aboved method but the AlarmReceiver.java is not get called**

I tried lot of ways to solve this but I missed something that I can't figured it out.

Can anyone help me to stop the triggered alarm and it's ringing sound .

Comment: Can you help me to solve  this @Kling Klang

Comment: you shoudn't hook your media player to a broadcast receiver. A better approach would be to start an activity or a service upon receiving a broadcast, then make this activity or service play a sound

Comment: I hope I did that in stopAlarm() function @KlingKlang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your architecture is broken. You don't use a `BroadcastReceiver` for persistent processing. A `BroadcastReceiver` has a very short lifecycle, you use it to trigger other things.

You've created a `MediaPlayer` instance in your `BroadcastReceiver` and are trying to control that in `onReceive()`. This is wrong. You should use a `Service` to manage and maintain the state of your `MediaPlayer`.

See if you can find some HOWTO guides on the Internet for how to build such an application.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidWasser

Comment: I almost tried all the ways to work this code but still I am struggling to make it work .can I get any help from you to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637793/cant-cancel-the-pendingintent-and-the-alarm-sound-in-android @DavidWasser